# PHP Online Test

Tags: php

я столкнулся с такой проблемой, создал онлайн тест и в значения $plusbox и $errorbox не увеличивается значение на 1, хоть я и задал условия $plusbox++ и $errorbox++

```
$errorbox = 0;
 $plusbox = 0;
 if(!isset($_REQUEST['GO'])) {

   if($_REQUEST['TXT_FORM_NAME'] == " ") {break;}

   if($_POST[FORM1] == A) {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

   if($_POST[FORM2] == C) {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

   if($_POST[FORM3] == B) {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

   if($_POST[FORM4] == A) {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

   if($_POST[FORM5] == A) {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

 }
```

Comment: Похоже у Вас просто не доходит до $plusbox++ и $errorbox++. Проверьте, что вообще приходит? Например, print_r($_REQUEST) или var_dump($_REQUEST['GO']) и var_dump($_REQUEST['TXT_FORM_NAME'])

Comment: break не работает в if, он "прерывает выполнение текущей структуры for, foreach, while, do-while или switch" (оффдок, php >= 7). И каким онлайн тестом пользуетесь? PHP Online Test, который я знаю, не посылает post/get

Comment: О боге. Это-ж кто вас, так учил программировать? Откройте книжку пожалуйста и почитайте АЗЫ!

Answer (score -1):

```
$errorbox = 0;
$plusbox = 0;
if(!isset($_REQUEST['GO'])) {

    if($_POST['FORM1'] == 'A') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

    if($_POST['FORM2'] == 'C') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

    if($_POST['FORM3'] == 'B') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

    if($_POST['FORM4'] == 'A') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

    if($_POST['FORM5'] == 'A') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

}
```

Работающий и протестированный пример:

```
<?php
$errorbox = 0;
$plusbox = 0;

if($_POST['FORM1'] == 'A') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

if($_POST['FORM2'] == 'C') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

if($_POST['FORM3'] == 'B') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

if($_POST['FORM4'] == 'A') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

if($_POST['FORM5'] == 'A') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

echo 'box -';
print_r($plusbox);
echo 'error -';
print_r($errorbox);


?>

<form method="post">
    <input name="FORM1">
    <input name="FORM2">
    <input name="FORM3">
    <input name="FORM4">
    <input name="FORM5">
    <button>fdsf</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Нет, даже с добавлениями одинарных кавычек не хочет увеличиваться значение...

Comment: @ilya Вы передавали неизвестные параметры. Если сейчас у Вас не проходит значение - значит надо искать ещё ошибки. И скорее всего - это `break` уберите его из кода.

Comment: @Ilya читайте комметны к вопросу. Там иногда полезное пишут.

Answer (score -1):

Проверьте своё решение, например так:

```
$_REQUEST['GO'] = null;
$_REQUEST['TXT_FORM_NAME'] = 'test';
$_POST['FORM1'] = 'A'; // верно
$_POST['FORM2'] = 'A'; // неверно
$_POST['FORM3'] = 'B'; // верно
$_POST['FORM4'] = 'A'; // верно
$_POST['FORM5'] = 'C'; // неверно

$errorbox = 0;
$plusbox = 0;

if(!isset($_REQUEST['GO'])) {
    if ($_REQUEST['TXT_FORM_NAME'] == " ") {return;}

    if($_POST['FORM1'] == 'A') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

    if($_POST['FORM2'] == 'C') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

    if($_POST['FORM3'] == 'B') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

    if($_POST['FORM4'] == 'A') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}

    if($_POST['FORM5'] == 'A') {$plusbox++;} else {$errorbox++;}
}

printf("errorbox: %d, plusbox: %d\n", $errorbox, $plusbox);
```

Я немного поправил ваш код, чтобы он не валился с ошибками.

Если результат вас устраивает, уберите тестовые данные и посмотрите а что у вас в приходит в массивы `$_REQUEST` и `$_POST`. Напишите `var_dump($_REQUEST, $_POST);`  посмотрите на вывод. При необходимости внесисте правки в HTML-форму или в php-код.